# What is the SQL ANY operator equivalent in JPQL?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Given the following Oracle sql query cooked for a `PreparedStatement`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE field1 = 'foo'
and field2 =ANY (substr( ? , 1, 2) || '00000000',
                 substr( ? , 1, 4) || '000000',
                 substr( ? , 1, 6) || '0000',
                 substr( ? , 1, 8) || '00',
                 ?
                )
```

I want to translate to a JPQL query. Reading the JPQL doc, `substr` becomes `substring`
and `ANY` stays as it is. In JPQL `ANY` expects a subquery.

How can I change the list into a subquery ? or should I use `IN` operator or should I generate a JPQL string with a bunch of OR conditions in it ?

**Oracle 10gR2**
**Java 5**
**JPA 2**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering that `= ANY(...)` is equivalent to `IN (...)` in SQL, you can safely use IN.

In fact, the `IN` predicate is defined in terms of the `ANY` predicate. Excerpt of the [SQL 1992](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) standard:

> 8.4  <in predicate>
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> <in predicate> ::=
>     <row value constructor>
>       [ NOT ] IN <in predicate value>
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> 2) Let RVC be the <row value constructor> and let IPV be the <in predicate value>.
>
> [...]
>
> 4) The expression
>
> ```
>   RVC IN IPV
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
>   RVC = ANY IPV
> ```

Then again, the `ANY` / `SOME` `<quantified comparison predicate>` operators are defined in a way similar to a bunch of `OR` connected predicates. Hence the answer is: You can use both `IN` or `OR`-connected predicates.

**Note:** While this answer explains things how they are in SQL, I'm pretty sure something similar applies to JPQL as well.

Comment: Tks for you response ! I 'll use IN operator